# Configuring DD-WRT to Route Based on Host Header

Tags: routing, router

I'm looking at flashing my Linksys to use DD-WRT... but only if it supports functionality that the base firmware doesn't have... which I actually want to use.

One of the routing features I've wanted for some time is the ability to route to a different computer on my network based on more than just he port number... namely the Host Header value. So I have DynDNS already setup to go to my router, but based on the subdomain, I'd like it to route to one computer or another in my internal network.

I've looked through the DD-WRT documentation, but it's pretty sparse in this area. Its so sparse, that I can't even tell if it's possible with this firmware right now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it'll be able to do that, even if you found a way to patch it yourself and allow for it.  You need a little more horsepower than what those linksys routers can provide to be able to reliably do packet inspection to pull out that info and route accordingly - in real time.

Why not setup an internal proxy, and have it redirect based on the host header value?  This way you just redirect to that, and then it will process the HTTP and redirect accordingly to your different hosts.

Comment: dd-wrt supports optional packages. The list is here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_list_of_Optware_packages . I see squid is available.  You have some work to do to understand how this all works.

Comment: @uSlackr - Not exactly an "answer" to my problem, but thanks for the pointer in a partial direction. Maybe I need to rethink the framework to my solution.

Comment: The way I see it is that you are asking for is not a routing problem.  Routing is a layer 3 function, you have an application layer problem.

Comment: @uSlackr I understand your point, and you're correct in that regard. But frankly, these "routers" do a heck of a lot more than simply routing right now anyway, from print sharing, to FTP server, to file server. So why suddenly the distinction on this?

Comment: Agreed - and the optional dd-wrt packages is one way to make that router do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

(Perhaps this should be its own answer)

As @sandroid said, what you want to do can be handled by a web proxy.  dd-wrt supports installation of software not compiled into the firmware (it is linux after all).

Read about [Optware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware) packaging first and implement the prerequisites.  Then install one of web proxies (nginx, squid, pound, etc) and configure it for your use.

[Packages](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_list_of_Optware_packages)